Sobolev spaces are smooth? Their dual is strictly convex?
Do you know any reference which says something about the:

Smoothness of the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ i.e. if the duality mapping $J\colon W^{1,p}(\Omega)\to W^{1,p}(\Omega)^*$ is a singleton.

Is $W^{1,p}(\Omega)^*$ strictly convex?


Here $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded domain and $\infty>p>1$ is any exponent.

For nice $\Omega$, Pelczynski and Wojciechowski proved that the Sobolev space is isomorphic to $L^p([0,1])$, see https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-0208(01)80041-4

There are a bunch of great books on Banach space geometry but sadly they often do not care very much about Sobolev spaces. There is Example 2.47 in Schuster at al: Regularization Methods in Banach Spaces if you want something directly quotable, although the authors also only point to other works.
However, one can also combine a bunch of results from, say, Cioranescu:  Geometry of Banach Spaces, Duality Mappings and Nonlinear Problems. For example like that:

For a reflexive Banach space $X$, $X$ is strictly convex [smooth] if and only if $X^*$ is smooth [strictly convex]. This is  Corollary II.1.4. So it is enough to establish that $W^{1,p}$ is smooth.
Theorem I.3.5 says that $X$ is smooth if and only if the norm is G-differentiable on $X \setminus \{0\}$.
In Chapter II.4 the classical result of Clarkson is established, that the $L^p$ spaces are uniformly convex, in particular strictly convex, so they are also smooth (go back and forth between $L^p$ and its dual). In particular, their norm is G-differentiable except for in $0$.
The norm on $W^{1,p}$ is a composition of $L^p$ norms and continuous linear operators $W^{1,p} \to L^p$ and thus inherits $G$-differentiability from the $L^p$ ones, so $W^{1,p}$ is smooth and its dual is strictly convex.

